# In oracle How to find if a particular value exists in a string which contains multiple values seperated by comma(,)

Tags: string, oracle, find, contains

I would like to find if TD003 or BA999 are avaialble in a particular column.

There is a possiblity of this column containing more than 20 values and I would like to check for a possible list of 100 values.

Comment: Is your list of 100 values static?

Comment: Please provide example table structure and data along with what you have tried so far so we are able to assist you better

Comment: If this is a school assignment, it's teaching your The Wrong Thing. NEVER store comma-separated values in a database field. If it's not a school assignment, same rule applies.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the INSTR function:

```
SELECT *
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  WHERE INSTR(COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES_FIELD, 'TD003') > 0 OR
        INSTR(COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES_FIELD, 'BA999') > 0
```

Best of luck.

### EDIT

Let's consider some sample data [from this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aada5/1):

```
CREATE TABLE SOME_TABLE(COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES_FIELD  VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES_FIELD) VALUES ('NOT THIS ONE');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES_FIELD) VALUES ('XYZ,ZTD003Y,ZZZ');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES_FIELD) VALUES ('12345BA99999999');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES_FIELD) VALUES ('OR THIS ONE');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES_FIELD) VALUES ('BUT THIS ONE TD003 IT''LL FIND JUST FINE');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES_FIELD) VALUES ('AS WELL ASBA999THIS ONE');
```

Given this data, the SQL statement above returns:

```
COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES_FIELD
XYZ,ZTD003Y,ZZZ
12345BA99999999
BUT THIS ONE TD003 IT'LL FIND JUST FINE
AS WELL ASBA999THIS ONE
```

`INSTR` returns the position of the search string (e.g. 'TD003') within the target string, so for example when the target string is

```
XYZ,ZTD003Y,ZZZ
```

`INSTR('XYZ,ZTD003Y,ZZZ', 'TD0003')` returns 6, which is the index of the first character of `TD0003` within the target string. If the search string is not found within the target string zero is returned.

Comment: This may fail on the case where the csv field is "XYZ,ZTD003Y,ZZZ".   I am assuming that it needs to be an exact match, rather than a contains.

Comment: The SQL I gave works fine for your test data as well as for some other examples I tossed in for fun. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aada5/1)

Comment: When searching for MOTHER in CHEMOTHERAPY, for some cases we want it to be a match, for other cases, we don't want it to be a match.  The op doesn't say which behavior he wants.  I suspect it is the second one.